# How to create blocking file descriptor in Unix?

Tags: c, file, unix, blocking

I would like to create blocking and non-blocking file descriptors in Unix's C. First, blocking:

```
fd = open("file.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_EXCL);
```

Is that right? Shouldn't I add some mode options, like 0666 for example?

How about non-blocking file? I have no idea for this.

I would like to achieve something like:

1. When I open it to write in it, and it's opened for writing, it's ok; if not, it blocks.
2. When I open it to read from it, and it's opened for reading, it's ok; if not, it blocks.

Comment: What do you mean under "blocking" file ?

Comment: By "blocking", do you mean that no other application should be able to access the file?

Comment: @LiMar: Im not so sure how to explain this: I mean, its default file "mode" in linux

Comment: @mazix I mean there is no such thing, as you can see from other answers.

Comment: File descriptors are blocking or non-blocking; files are not.  Add O_NBLOCK to the options if you want a non-blocking descriptor.  Note that opening a FIFO for reading or writing will block unless there's a process with the FIFO open for the other operation, or you specify O_NBLOCK.  (If you open it for read and write, it is non-blocking.)

Comment: You're update is...mysterious.   If you open the file for writing, then it is opened for writing, so it should be OK.  What is the 'if not, it blocks' about?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think thats the issue. I ment file descriptor, and wrote file... So, should I add `O_NBLOCK`to create non-blocking but what about blocking file descriptor?

Comment: @mazix euh, omit it? (By the way, the blocking/non-blocking file descriptor doesn't mean what you think it does.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File descriptors are blocking or non-blocking; files are not. Add O_NBLOCK to the options in the `open()` call if you want a non-blocking file descriptor.

Note that opening a FIFO for reading or writing will block unless there's a process with the FIFO open for the other operation, or you specify O_NBLOCK. If you open it for read and write, the `open()` is non-blocking (will return promptly); I/O operations are still controlled by whether you set O_NBLOCK or not.

The updated question is not clear.  However, if you're looking for 'exclusive access to the file' (so that no-one else has it open), then neither O_EXCL nor O_NBLOCK is the answer.  O_EXCL affects what happens when you create the file; the create will fail if the file already exists.  O_NBLOCK affects whether a `read()` operation will block when there's no data available to read.  If you read the POSIX [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) description, there is nothing there that allows you to request 'exclusive access' to a file.

To answer the question about file mode: if you include O_CREAT, you need the third argument to `open()`. If you omit O_CREAT, you don't need the third argument to `open()`. It is a varargs function:

```
int open(const char *filename, int options, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't I add some mode options?

You should, if the file is write-only and to be created if nonexistent. In this case, `open()` expects a third argument as well, so omitting it results in undefined behavior.

**Edit:**

The updated question is even more confusing...

> when I open it to write in it, and it's opened for writing, it's ok; if not it blocks.

Why would you need that? See, if you try to write to a file/file descriptor not opened for writing, `write()` will return -1 and you can check the error code stored in `errno`. Tell us what you're trying to achieve by this bizarre thing you want instead of overcomplicating and messing up your code.

(Remarks in parentheses:

> I would like to create blocking and non-blocking file

What's that?

> in unix's C

Again, there's no such thing. There is **the** C language, which is platform-independent.)

Comment: thanks for explanation. Could you be so kind and see my edit and say if sth like that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are calling a blocking file (blocking IO in Unix means that the IO operations wait for the data to be available or for a sure failure, they are opposed to non-blocking IO which returns immediately if there is no available data).

- You always need to specify a mode when opening with O_CREAT.
- The open you show will fails if the file already exists (when fixed for the above point).
- Unix has no standard way to lock file for exclusive access excepted that. There are advisory locks (but all programs must respect the protocol).  Some have mandatory lock extension.  The received wisdom is not to rely on either kind of locking when accessing network file system.